# dotenv-webpack enviornment variables not working on Github actions

Tags: reactjs, webpack, environment-variables, github-actions, dotenv

I'm using `dotenv-webpack` to set up the enviornment varibles from `webpack`. And push my code build to S3 then. I set up `.env` file on my local with `APP_BASE = http://localhost:3000` inside `.env`.

I have created the github action `workflow.yml`:

```
name: React CI

on:
    push:
        branches:
            - "main"

jobs:
    build:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest

        strategy:
            matrix:
                node-version: [15.x]

        steps:
            - uses: actions/checkout@v1
            - run: npm install
            - run: npm run build
            - uses: jakejarvis/s3-sync-action@master
              with:
                  args: --acl public-read --follow-symlinks --delete
              env:
                  AWS_S3_BUCKET: ${{ secrets.AWS_S3_BUCKET }}
                  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
                  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
                  AWS_REGION: "ap-southeast-2"
                  SOURCE_DIR: "dist"
                  APP_BASE: ${{ secrets.APP_BASE }}
```

On my github actions secrets, I have added the secrets:

[image]

on webpack settings, I have set `systemvars: true`:

```
plugins: [
        new Dotenv({
            systemvars: true,
        }),
```

It's working on my localhost.

I didn't commit `.env` file to my repository, and when I push code to github, github console output: `Failed to load ./.env.`.

[image]

When I check the compiled file, it shows `var e="MISSING_ENV_VAR".APP_BASE;`. That means github action didn't catch the `APP_BASE` on the secrets.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: You can't use `DotEnv` plugin in your CI webpack build without a `.env` file can you?

Answer (score 1):

I found the error, I should move the env varible to the higher level as the current one I put is for task on S3, not for build.

```
name: React CI

on:
    push:
        branches:
            - "main"

env:
    APP_BASE: ${{ secrets.APP_BASE }}

jobs:
    build:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest

        strategy:
            matrix:
                node-version: [15.x]

        steps:
            - uses: actions/checkout@v1
            - run: npm install
            - run: npm run build
            - uses: jakejarvis/s3-sync-action@master
              with:
                  args: --acl public-read --follow-symlinks --delete
              env:
                  AWS_S3_BUCKET: ${{ secrets.AWS_S3_BUCKET }}
                  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
                  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
                  AWS_REGION: "ap-southeast-2"
                  SOURCE_DIR: "dist"
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is comitting `.env` to your repo with values suitable for local dev and containing no real secrets. Then put all your secrets in GitHub and when CI runs the local dev values will be overwritten by the ones in [GitHub secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets) via the `systemvars` setting.

Comment: I have set `systemvars `to `true` and add GitHub Secrets. But not working.

Comment: Because you have to commit the `.env` file.